# how to disable seeking on MediaStyle notification?

Tags: android, android-mediasession, android-notification.mediastyle, android-media3

I working on a audio player like app and show audio progress and info on notification using media3.
I want to show only progress on mediaStyle notification and the user does not able to change progress.
I think I must set some value to the media session but don't know what.